# Prevent "broken pipe" for child process in bash

Tags: linux, bash, subprocess, signals, sigpipe

This has a broken pipe error which I want to suppress:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /tmp/foo

tail -f /tmp/foo &

PID=$!

echo before
kill -9 $PID
echo after

while true;
do
    echo x
    sleep 1
done
```

output:

```
before
after
x
./test.sh: line 17: 23327 Killed                  tail -f /tmp/foo
x
x
^C
```

I tried `trap -- '' PIPE` and subshells and `bash -c "tail -f /tmp/foo" 2>/dev/null &` but the message persists.

How do I suppress it?

Comment: there's no "broken pipe" here. do you mean the `... line 17: 23327 Killed ...` message?

Comment: That's not a broken pipe error, it's the shell's job control feature reporting that a process it was managing has been killed. To remove it from job control, add `disown $PID` before killing it.

Comment: you can also do `{ kill -9 $PID && wait $PID; } &> /dev/null `